# Why is this prime test so slow compared to this other one?

Tags: python

Here are two prime test functions, I wrote the first :

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n == 2: 
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    boolean = True
    i = 3
    while i <= n / 2:
        if n % i == 0:
            boolean = False
            break
        i += 2
    return boolean
```

---

```
def is_prime(n):

    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

For some reason I don't understand, the second one is way much quicker than the first. 
For example, if I test the number 1000004249 which is prime, I get the answer in 0.015 seconds with the second one, while the first one takes so much time I just quit the program.. 
I really don't get why there is so much difference.

If anybody can help me see where is the problem, I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: `n/2` is a lot bigger than `int(n**0.5)+1`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica To be specific, the first one has to loop `500002125` times, while the second has to loop `31623` times.

Comment: I didn't realise the **, in my head it was just a *. I don't even know what ** represents, I'll check. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @Ozz. `**` is exponent. Some other languages use `^` instead. Raising to the half power means square root

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes I just saw that. Also just understood why you can stop your loop at n**(1/2)... I was dumb not thinking about it, my bad.

Comment: the second consume more store and is quicker while the first one consume less storage and speed slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of repetitions the first function has to do grows linearly with `n`. For the second function, the number of repetitions  grows at a much slower rate (proportional to the square root of `n`).

For small `n` there will not be much difference in performance. For large `n`, (e.g. `n = 1000004249`) `n/2` is orders of magnitude larger than `int(n**0.5)+1` as already stated, and the first function has to do more repetitions.